# Show that $\mu^{*} (A) = \mu (A)$ if $\mu$ is countably additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let X be a set, let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra of subsets of X, and let $\mu$ be a fintiely additive measure on $\mathcal{A}$. For each subset $A$ of $X$ let $\mu^{*}(A)$  be the infimum of of the set of sums $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{k})$, where $\{A_{k}\}$ ranges over the sequences of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ for which $A \subset \cup_{k = 1}^{\infty} A_{k}$.

Show that if $\mu$ is countably additive ( in the sense that $\mu(\cup
_{k} A_{k}) = \sum_{k}\mu(A_{k})$ holds whener $\{ A_{k} \}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$ for which $\cup_{k} A_{k}$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$), then each $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies $\mu(A) = \mu^{*}(A)$.

We know that $\mu^{*}$ is an outer measureand that each set in $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable.

My incomplete try:

First, for the sequence $A_{1} = A$ and $A_{k} = \emptyset$ for $k \geq 2$ we have

$\mu^{*}(A) \leq \sum_{k} \mu(A_{k}) = \mu(A)$.

So we now want $\mu(A) \leq \mu^{*}(A)$

Let $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and let $\{A_{k}\}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $A \subset \cup_{k} A_{k}$ and $\mu^{*}(\cup_{k} A_{k}) \leq \mu^{*}(A) + \epsilon$ for an $\epsilon > 0$.

By defining $A'_{n} = \cap_{k}^{n}A_{k}$, we get a disjoint sequence $\{A'_{n}\}$ such that $\cup_{n} A'_{n} = \cup_{k}A_{k}$ and $\mu*(\cup_{n} A'_{n}$) = $\mu^{*}(\cup_{k}A_{k})$, so we can assume that $\{A_{k} \}$ is disjoint from beginning.

Let $B \in \mathcal{A}$ (all sets in $\mathcal{A}$ are measurable).

Then $\mu(A) = \mu(A \cap B ) + \mu(A \cap B^{C})$ since $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{A}$.

$\mu(A \cap B ) + \mu(A \cap B^{C}) \leq \sum_{k} \mu(A_{k}\cap B) + \mu(A_{k} \cap B^{C})$

since $\{A_{k} \cap B \}$ is a covering sequence of $A\cap B$ and similary $\{A_{k} \cap B^{C} \}$ covers $A \cap B$.

$ \sum_{k} \mu(A_{k}\cap B) + \mu(A_{k} \cap B^{C}) = \sum_{k} \mu(A_{k}) $,

since $\mu$ is a measure and $ A_{k} \cap B , A_{k} \cap B^{C} \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $k$.

If $\cup_{k} A_{k} \in \mathcal{A}$, then

$  \sum_{k} \mu(A_{k}) = \mu(\cup_{k} A_{k})  \leq \mu^{*}(A) + \epsilon$

and we have the wanted inequality.

However, as I understand it, the key problem is that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra so we do not know if we for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$ can find a disjoint sequence $\{A_{k} \}$ such that $A \subset \cup_{k} A_{k}$?

Or can we create such a sequence by saying that " Let $\{C_{k}\}$ be sequence where each $C_{k}$ consists of one element of $A$." Then $C_{k}$ would be disjoint and $\cup_{k} C_{k} = A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Any feedback is appreciated!

/ Erik

Comment: If $\mathscr A$ is algebra, then $X\in \mathscr A$, which gives you a disjoint sequence that covers any $A \subset X$. Anyway, dealing with outer measure $\mu^*$ can be consulted in classical "Real analysis" by Folland - it also covers the theorem you are talking about here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But we must also have that for any $\epsilon > 0 $, $\mu*(\cup_{k} A_{k})$ $\leq \mu* (A) + \epsilon$. Maybe my approach is not feasible.

Comment: Well, by definition 
$$
  \mu^*(A) = \sup\left\{\mu(B):B = \bigcup_k A_k\right\}
$$
so that the existence of such sequence follows from the definition of the supremum. Does it clarify the thing?

Comment: Do you mean $\mu^* (A) = \sup \{ \mu(B) : B = \cup_{k} A_{k} \subset A \}$? And then $\mu^*(A) \geq \mu(A)$ ?

Comment: sorry, I've forgotten the inclusion. Yes, clearly $\mu^*(A)\geq \mu(A)$ whenever $A\in \mathscr A$ since one of the sequences supremum is taken over is $A_k \equiv A$ for all $k$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. However, in this case $\mu^*(A) = \inf \{\sum_{k} A_{k} : A \subset \cup_{k}A_{k}, A_{k} \in \mathcal{A} \forall k \}$. Then we shall show that $\mu(A) = \mu^*(A)$ if $A\in \mathcal{A}$, if $\mu$ is countably additive. So I guess the purpose with the exercise is to show that equality holds with help from countably additivity and for that we need a disjoint sequence $\{ A_{k} \}$, covering $A$ and $\cup_{k} A_{k} \in \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8190/discussion-between-ilya-and-erik)

Comment: let us proceed in the linked chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E \in \mathcal{A}.$ Using trivial covering $E=E \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \dots$ we conclude that $\mu^*(E) \le \mu(E).$

On other way, if $\displaystyle E \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ is one covering of set $E$ with sets from $\mathcal{A}$, then $$E=E \cap \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (E \cap E_n),$$ with $E \cap E_n \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ and then from countable subadditivity of measure $\mu$ we find $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_n) \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E \cap E_n) \ge \mu(E).$$ Using fact that covering $E \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ was arbitrary, we find $\mu^* (E) \ge \mu(E)$, so we proved our statement.

Comment: So then we actually do not need that $\mu$ is countably additive.

Comment: @Erik We need that $\mu$ is countably additive to prove that $\mu$ is countably subadditive.

Comment: Yes I see,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so instead of editing I try giving an answer myself.

Let $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and let $\{A_{k}\}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $A \subset \cup_{k} A_{k}$ and $\mu^{*}(\cup_{k} A_{k}) \leq \mu^{*}(A) + \epsilon$ for an $\epsilon > 0$.

By defining $A'_{n} = A_{n} \setminus \cup_{k = 1}^{n-1} A_{k}$, we get a disjoint sequence $\{A'_{n}\}$ such that $\cup_{n} A'_{n} = \cup_{k}A_{k}$ and $\mu^*(\cup_{n} A'_{n}$) = $\mu^{*}(\cup_{k}A_{k})$. Then since $\{ A'_{k} \}$ are disjoint, we can create a new disjoint sequence $\{ C_{k} \}$ where $C_{k} = A'_{k} \cap A $. Then $\cup_{k} C_{k} = A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Using the countable additivity of $\mu$ we get

$ \mu(A) = \mu(\cup_{k} C_{k}) = \sum_{k} \mu (C_{k}) \leq \sum_{k} \mu(A_{k}) \leq \mu^*(A) + \epsilon $.

Since $\epsilon $ was arbitrary we have the wanted inequality and $\mu(A) = \mu^*(A)$ whenever $A\in \mathcal{A}$.